# Making a Venn Diagram from a Dataframe

Tags: r, venn-diagram

Hi so I have a dataframe that looks like this:

df1:

| Name | Event1 | Event 2 | Event3 | Event4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amanda | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Emily | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| George | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Baker | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Lee | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Jorge | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

My goal is to create a venn diagram, where there are four events that makes the four circles in a venn diagram. And say if within a row, if all four events are equal to 1, then that would contribute to the inner most middle value. Whereas if there was a 1 for event 1 and event 3, I would have a value that is tallied for the area that engulfs the venn diagram ring for event 1 and 3.

I looked into using the ggvenn package and the VennDiagram approach, but neither is working in my favor and I would appreciate any help please. Thank you!

I went ahead and posted the code below for the data frame:

```
# Creating the df1
Name <- c("Amanda", "Emily", "George", "Baker", "Lee", "Jorge")
Event1 <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0)
Event2 <- c(1,0,0,0,1,1)
Event3 <- c(1,1,0,1,1,0)
Event4 <- c(1,1,0,0,1)
df1 <- data.frame(Name, Event1, Event2, Event3, Event4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the order of columns in your dataframe and 'convert' each Event column from "1/0" to "TRUE/FALSE" the ggvenn package works as expected, i.e.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("ggvenn")
library(ggvenn)
#> Loading required package: grid

Name <- c("Amanda", "Emily", "George", "Baker", "Lee", "Jorge")
Event1 <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0)
Event2 <- c(1,0,0,0,1,1)
Event3 <- c(1,1,0,1,1,0)
Event4 <- c(1,1,0,0,1, 0)
df1 <- data.frame(Event1, Event2, Event3, Event4, Name)

df1 %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Event"), as.logical)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_venn(aes(A = Event1, B = Event2, C = Event3, D = Event4),
            set_names = Name)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I was getting an error when "Name" was the first column in the dataframe ('column 1 isn't logical') so moving that column and changing the 0/1 to TRUE/FALSE made sense.

Comment: Is it mandatory to convert the data to TRUE/FALSE for Venn diagram? If I have continuous numeric data, how can I draw Venn diagram?

Comment: Thank you @jared_mamrot ! If say the word "Event" was not all uniform across, how would i adjust that section of the code? (So I can better understand future scenarios)

Comment: You can also specify which columns to exclude, e.g. `mutate(across(-c(Name), as.logical))` (this means "for every column except for "Name", convert the 0/1's to FALSE/TRUE's). You can add in other variables too, e.g. `mutate(across(-c(Name, another_variable, a_different_variable), as.logical))`. This is all explained really well in [the docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)